# What is the best way to visualize the head-to-head records?

Tags: python, pandas, graph, visualization

I have a data frame looks like this:

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'team':[1,2,3,2,1,1,3,4,1,2], 'opp_team':[2,1,2,3,3,4,1,1,2,1], 'result':[1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0]})
```

The result column has 1 representing a victory and 0 representing a defeat. I want to figure out the best way to present the head to head record on a graph.

I was thinking of a pair plot, but I think it won't work because it will not show the count of victory and defeat. In the example above team 1 played against team 2 2 times, and won both. So, the graph should show the count as well.

What can I try to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just show them in 2 separate plots, 1 plot showing the total number of head-to-head records, the other showing the total winning rate of a team against another (winning rate of the other team = losing rate of the team).

To do this, I think the dataframe needs to be restructured such that it only shows 1 game ID per row. To allow for ease of grouping, sort the `team` and `opp_team` such that the index for `team` is always smaller than the index for `opp_team`

I generated a sample data set, how I would summarize and plot it, for your reference:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def generate_data(num_data=100, num_teams=4):

    team = np.random.randint(1,1 + num_teams,num_data)
    opp_team = np.random.randint(1,1 + num_teams,num_data)

    while len(opp_team[opp_team == team]) > 0:
        opp_team[opp_team == team] = np.random.randint(1,1 + num_teams,len(opp_team[opp_team == team]))

    results = np.round(np.random.rand(100))    

    return team, opp_team, results

def reorder_team(team, opp_team, result):

    if team > opp_team:
        team, opp_team = opp_team, team
        result = 1 - result

    return team, opp_team, result

# Generate data and get summary by team match-ups
team, opp_team, results = generate_data()

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'team':team,'opp_team':opp_team,'results':results}, dtype='int')
df = pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda x : reorder_team(x['team'], x['opp_team'], x['results']),axis=1).to_list(), 
                  columns=df.columns)
df[['team','opp_team']] = 'Team ' + df[['team','opp_team']].astype(str)

df_summary = df.groupby(['team','opp_team']).agg(['sum','count'])
df_summary.columns = ['wins', 'total']
df_summary.reset_index(inplace=True)
df_summary['team_winrate'] = (df_summary['wins'] / df_summary['total'])
df_summary['opp_team_winrate'] = 1 - df_summary['team_winrate']
```

which yields:

[image]

and you can plot them using the following script (or write your own using your favorite library):

```
fig, (ax_count, ax_win) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(12,6))

y_locs = list(range(len(df_summary)))

ax_count.barh(y_locs, width=df_summary['total'], color='tab:gray')
ax_count.set_yticks(y_locs)
ax_count.set_yticklabels(df_summary['team'] + ' VS ' + df_summary['opp_team'])
ax_count.set_title('Total No. of Match Ups')
ax_count.set_xticks([])

for loc in ['top','left','right','bottom']:
    ax_count.spines[loc].set_visible(False)

for p in ax_count.patches:
    ax_count.annotate(f'{p.get_width()}',
                      (p.get_x() + p.get_width(), p.get_y() + p.get_height()/2.), 
                      ha='right', va='center', xytext=(-5,0), textcoords='offset points', 
                      color='white',fontweight='heavy')

ax_win.barh(y_locs, width=df_summary['team_winrate'], color='tab:blue')
ax_win2 = ax_win.twinx()
ax_win2.barh(y_locs, width=df_summary['opp_team_winrate'], 
             left=df_summary['team_winrate'], color='tab:red')

ax_win.set_yticks(y_locs)
ax_win.set_yticklabels(df_summary['team'])
ax_win2.set_yticks(y_locs)
ax_win2.set_yticklabels(df_summary['opp_team'])

ax_win.set_xlim(0,1)
ax_win.set_title('Winning Rate')
ax_win.set_xticks([])

for loc in ['top','left','right','bottom']:
    ax_win.spines[loc].set_visible(False)
    ax_win2.spines[loc].set_visible(False)

for p in ax_win.patches:
    ax_win.annotate(f'{p.get_width() * 100 :.0f} %',
                      (0, p.get_y() + p.get_height()/2.), 
                      ha='left', va='center', xytext=(10,0), textcoords='offset points', 
                      color='white',fontweight='heavy')

    ax_win2.annotate(f'{(1 - p.get_width()) * 100 :.0f} %',
                      (1, p.get_y() + p.get_height()/2.), 
                      ha='right', va='center', xytext=(-10,0), textcoords='offset points', 
                      color='white',fontweight='heavy')

plt.show()
```

[image]